# How to rewrite this code using recursion?

Tags: javascript

```
// Sum all integers below a given integer.
// sumBelow(10); // 45
// sumBelow(7); // 21

var sumBelow = function(n) {
 var sum = 0;
 for(var i =0;i<n; i++) {
   sum += i;
 }
  return sum;
};
```

Hello everyone,
Can someone please show me how to do the code above using recursion in JavaScript?

Comment: We don't do your homework here.

Comment: n*(n+1)/2 often responded

Answer (score 1):

For your specific code, the equivalent recursion would be:

```js
function sumBelow(n) {
    return n-1 >= 0 ? (n-1) + sumBelow(n-1) : n;
}

console.log(sumBelow(10));
console.log(sumBelow(7));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const sum = num => num && (num + sum(num - 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int addNumbers(int n)
{
if(n != 0)
    return n + addNumbers(n-1);
else
    return n;
}
```